# How can I replace a hard drive running BootCamp?

Tags: time-machine, hard-drive, bootcamp, windows

I have actually looked online a bit and found this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2069302?start=0&tstart=0

I have a user that sent me their Macbook Air running OSX 10.6.4 and bootcamp.  They only use Windows 7 on it, never booting to OSX, and now their bootcamp partition is full.

I have bought her a new drive from here: http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/SSDAPMB240/

However, here's my issue (besides not knowing macs):

I don't have the original OSX DVD, and neither does she.  I've decided to order one from Amazon Prime (10.6.3) which is close enough I'd presume to get this done and will work on the mac without causing licensing issues.

My question now is: am I going down the right path to get this user a new hdd?  Are there other means/methods that are more commonly used to do this in the mac community?

Comment: Hey have you looked at this post? It may help you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/74404/10733, FWIW I would be doing exactly the same thing as you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was going down the right path...or at least it "works".

Here's the steps I took (following the link I posted in the OP):

1. Format external hard drive as extended (journaled) inside OSX
2. Export Boot Camp image using Winclone 2.2 (free online still) to an external HDD in a folder on the external HDD.
3. Turn on Time Machine and use external HDD as backup volume. Wait for Time Machine to copy all the files from the internal HDD to external HDD.
4. Eject Time Machine volume and unplug external hard drive.
5. Swap internal HDD with new HDD. (this part will be based on which drive you bought.  I got mine from OWC/MacSales and they have videos to help with the install.
6. Boot from Snow Leopard install disc (hold down options key and choose the DVD). (I originally didn't have one so I ordered one from Amazon with Prime overnight.
7. Select "Disk Utility" in Utilities after boot and format the new hard drive as Mac Extended (journaled).
8. Select "Restore System from Backup" in Utilities to copy the system and user files from external HDD to new internal HDD.
9. Reboot with OS installed on HDD rather than install disc.
10. Launch Boot Camp Assistant to create a new Boot Camp partition on new hard drive.  Here I chose a very large one (bigger than the original backup) since I needed more space...the whole point of the HDD upgrade.
11. Import Boot Camp image from external HDD to new Boot Camp partition on new internal HDD using Winclone.